# Why does this HTML page not work?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why only the top and bottom tables in this code are displayed. The middle PDF exists, there is no type of error shown, the PDF just does not show up on the page. Any ideas?

```
<h1>Continuing Education</h1>
<table id="tblouter">
  <tr>
    <td id="bordernone_aligncenter" rowspan="2" width="200">
      <img src="images/random/LauraMortimer.jpg" alt="Laura Mortimer" width="170" height="250"/>
    </td>
    <td id="bordernone_aligncenter">
      <b>
        Introduction to Conversational ASL for Dental Professionals<br>
        Wednesday, October 7 from 6 – 9 p.m.<br>
        Location TBD
      </b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="bordernone_alignleft">
      <b>Laura Mortimer</b>, BEI II interpreter, graduated from Mott Community College’s Sign Language Interpreter Education program and has been employed as an educational interpreter, video relay interpreter, freelance interpreter, agency coordinator, and instructor. As an instructor, she prepares aspiring ASL/English interpreting students for the language demands and environmental challenges that will be faced as certified interpreters.<br>
      <br>
      <b>Course Overview:</b>
      <ul>
        <li>Discuss possible misconceptions about the language
        <li>Learn how to work with deaf/hard of hearing patients in the office
        <li>Practice basic signs and greetings
      </ul> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
For more information contact us through our facebook page:<br>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/GDDAS/" target="_blank">Genesee District Dental Assistants Society</a><br>
<br>
<br>
<table id="tblouter">
  <tr>
    <td id="bordernone_aligncenter">
      <embed src="images/random/MOM20151024.pdf" width="900px" height="1150px">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>    
<br>
<br>
<table id="tblouter">
  <tr>
    <td id="bordernone_aligncenter">
      <embed src="images/random/MOM2015.pdf" width="900px" height="1150px">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/ — 17 errors (more if you count the incorrect semantics)

Comment: Where did you get the idea that you can just embed a PDF using an embed tag? It actually would have taken you less time to Google this rather than posting a question on Stack Overflow... [Google Search Results for "html embed pdf"](https://www.google.com.au/#q=html+embed+pdf)

Comment: Thank Christian. But like I mentioned, the second PDF is embedded just fine. The first one is not showing.

Comment: @Quentin about the only thing that validator correctly identified was the duplicate identifier. Is the duplicate ID an issue?

Comment: @Christian Varga If you'd like to see it in action, http://www.gddas.com then click on Announcements - Continuing Ed

Comment: Should I change the id to a class? Anyone? I guess a class does make more sense overall. I'll try that.

Comment: @user2021539 Sorry, I stand corrected. Just never used an embed tag before, didn't realise it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the name of your first table id "tbleouter" and also change the name of first td id "bordernone_aligncenter" in your html and css both.

Comment: Changing the id "tblouter" didn't help. :( So far I don't see a change with the classes being changed but that may be a cache issue.

Comment: In one page you should use one id only one time and you are using same id many time that is wrong. And let me know are you loading that pdf online or offline ?

Comment: In firefox it's working fine, i have checked it using without any css. Means no embed problem.

Comment: Thank you everyone. It turned out to be a simple cache issue that Firefox wasn't clearing (even though the cache was manually emptied several times). The code works perfectly now (even the "embed" tag that I was chastised about).